# How can I generate SQL with WHERE statement in EFCore Query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write the EF Query with a filter and the generated SQL is not using WHERE statement on the SQL Server.  It extracts all data and does the filter on the Client's Memory.  I am quite worried about the performance and would like to apply the filter on the SQL Server.

#### The requirement is to count the number of records in an Hour time slot.

```
public async Task<int> GetNumberofSchedules(DateTime dt)
{
    return await _context.Schedules.CountAsync(
        s => s.state == 0
                && s.AppointmentDate.Value.Date == dt.Date
                && s.AppointmentTime.Value.Hours >= dt.Hour
                && s.AppointmentTime.Value.Hours < dt.AddHours(1).Hour
        );
}
```

**Sample Data**

if given DateTime is `07/04/2017 08:20`, it should return the number of records between `07/04/2017 08:00` and `07/04/2017 09:00`

The count does return 6 which is correct but when I trace the generated SQL in SQL Profiler, it's retrieving all data.

[image]

**Generated SQL in SQL Profiler**

> SELECT
>   [s].[EnrolmentRecordID], [s].[AF1], [s].[AcademicYearID], [s].[AdminName], [s].[AppForm], [s].[AppointmentDate],
>   [s].[AppointmentTime], [s].[BDT], [s].[BKSB], [s].[DateCreated],
>   [s].[DateModified], [s].[Employer], [s].[EmployerInvited],
>   [s].[EmployerReps], [s].[MIAPP], [s].[NI], [s].[ProposedQual],
>   [s].[SMT], [s].[StudentInvited], [s].[StudentName]
>
> FROM 
>       [dbo].[EN_Schedules] AS [s]

I would like to amend my EF code to generate WHERE statement and do the filter on the server side.  How can I achieve it?

**Update1:**

If I remove filters for TimeSpan value, it generates the correct SQL statement as the following:  So, it seems to me that I need to apply the filter differently for TimeSpan Field.

> exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[EN_Schedules] AS [s]
>   WHERE ([s].[state] = 0) AND (CONVERT(date, [s].[AppointmentDate]) =
>   @__dt_Date_0)',N'@__dt_Date_0 datetime2(7)',@__dt_Date_0='2017-04-07
>   00:00:00'

**Update2: **

By using Ivan's solution, I ended up doing like this:

```
var startTime = new TimeSpan(dt.Hour, 0, 0);
var endTime = new TimeSpan(dt.Hour + 1, 0, 0);

return await _context.Schedules.CountAsync(
     s => s.state == 0
          && s.AppointmentDate.Value.Date == dt.Date
          && s.AppointmentTime.Value >= startTime
          && s.AppointmentTime.Value < endTime

 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed converted to client evaluation - looks like many `TimeSpan` operations are still not supported well by EF Core.

After a lot of trial and error, the only way currently you can make it translate to SQL is to prepare `TimeSpan` limits as variables and use them inside the query:

```
var startTime = new TimeSpan(dt.Hour, 0, 0);
var endTime = startTime + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

return await _context.Schedules.CountAsync(
    s => s.state == 0
        && s.AppointmentDate.Value.Date == dt.Date
        && s.AppointmentTime.Value >= startTime
        && s.AppointmentTime.Value < endTime
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Client Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) is the reason.

Disable it with `ConfigureWarnings` call. It will give an exception if a LINQ statement cann't be translated to SQL:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer("foo_connstr")
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. And the solution is... :)

Comment: @IvanStoev probably there is no LINQ solution because we still don't have a `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3554
A stored procedure can be the option.